# How can I make React Link wait until I click it and a method returns result before redirecting?

Tags: reactjs

I have this following code to render. It is part of a login form. I have this Link, and when I click it, it goes to the handleSubmit method where I verify the credentials (username&pass). What I want is to do different stuff depending on the result. If the credentials are correct go to my welcome page, otherwise stay on this one.
At the moment it is constantly calling the handleSubmit method, not waiting until I click on it. How can I change this to work?

```
<Link to={`/` + this.handleSubmit} style={loginButton} onClick={this.handleSubmit}> Register </Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the jump event in your `handleSubmit`, just like this

```
<div style={loginButton} onClick={this.handleSubmit}> Register </div>

handleSubmit = () => {
  ...
  // flag is true while the credentials are correct 
  if(flag){
      widow.location.href = '/' + path
      router.push('/'+ path) // use react-router
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, i don't really know how to use a react-router, I thought maybe there was a more simple way to do it. Like get my function to return the desired path string, and only start redirect after i received the output